# Why can't I import Control.Monad.Writer while I have mtl-2.2.2 installed?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I am trying to import Writer monad which is defined in `mtl-2.2.2` package which I have installed  as I checked with `ghc-pkg list`.

When I tried to do `import Control.Monad.Writer` in `ghci` it is giving me an error.
I don't understand why?

```
Prelude> import Control.Monad.Writer  

<no location info>: error:
    Could not find module ‘Control.Monad.Writer’
    Perhaps you meant
      Control.Monad.Fail (from base-4.11.1.0)
      Control.Monad.Fix (from base-4.11.1.0)
      Control.Monad.Zip (from base-4.11.1.0)
```

Comment: When you start up ghci, does it by chance show a text like `Loaded package environment from ...`?

Comment: yes. It shows text like that.

Comment: That file tells ghci what libraries should be available for a session. Maybe it's filtering mtl for some reason. You could try to rename that file to something like `.xxx.environment` so that ghci doesn't pick it, and see if you can `import Control.Monad.Writer` then. An alternative is to actually add `mtl` to that file using cabal-install, by means of an invocation like `cabal install --lib mtl`. Does any of that work?

Comment: @danidiaz it worked my renaming that file. Now I can import it . Thanks!

Comment: one more question, how can I add libraries to that environment? In other words how can I tell ghci to include some specific libraries? @danidiaz

Comment: You can add libraries to an environment file using the cabal executable (this doesn't require creating a cabal project). For example `cabal install --lib --package-env your_env_file_or_folder_here mtl`. The docs for package environment files are here https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/packages.html#package-environments the docs for the cabal install command are here https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cabal-commands.html#cabal-v2-install Notice that you can have *local* package environment files in different folders, each with a different package combination.