# Why is installing a Haskell package not working?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I am trying to install the `binary-bits` package. I ran `cabal install binary-bits`, the directory exists in my install directory but import doesn't work. The package is also not listed as installed when I run `cabal list --installed`. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: So, here is how I solved it.

The package was downloaded into /store/.

`cd` to the directory with the zipped package, unzip it, run `runhaskell Setup configure`, `runhaskell Setup build` and `runhaskell Setup install` with admin privileges.

Then in ghci, first I had to `:l <package>` and only after that can I import it normally.

Comment: May I assume you're running cabal 3.0 or newer?  The fix is you need to install libraries with `--lib`.  There are a number of stackoverflow questions on this that might shed some light.

Comment: For instance, [this question I answered a while ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61512017/2751851) is probably relevant.

Comment: OK, I made [a PR that makes it red](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/pull/6857).  Feel free to comment with anything else you think would be helpful in noticing this critical and frequently missed message.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Hi, sorry for the late reply. Yes I did install it with `--lib` but it didn't work. I am not sure where exactly the problem was, but I ended up reinstalling Haskell Platform as I was using an old version. Now it is working fine. Thanks for help anyway.